# c++: creating a timer/alarm class that can call any function?

Tags: c++, timer, function-pointers

The dilemma I have is I want to create a timer (also called an "alarm", using Game Maker terminology) that can call ANY function after its time expires. Not just have it call a specific function pointer based on a specific signature.

So, simple question: Is this possible?

Comment: I have a function that takes in an Egg and a Cheese and returns an Omelet.  I hand my function to your timer.  When the timer's alarm goes off, with what Egg and what Cheese will you call my function?

Comment: Robert Cooper: with the Egg and Cheese you gave me when you handed me the function of course!

Comment: C++11 will do exactly this with `std::async` and `std::timed_mutex`; you shouldn't have to implement anything. However, I don't have time to read up on it and create an example :v( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Q&A with the Question poster

I have a function that takes in an Egg and a Cheese and returns an Omelet. I hand my function to your timer. When the timer's alarm goes off, with what Egg and what Cheese will you call my function? - Robert Cooper

@RobertCooper with the Egg and Cheese you gave me when you handed me the function of course! – nightcracker

@nightcracker: So when I set an alarm, I need to give the timer a function, an Egg, and a Cheese.  Then again, if my callback instead takes in a Bacon, a HomeFries, Sausage, and an Oatmeal, I need to give the alarm a function, a Bacon, a HomeFries, Sausage, and an Oatmeal.  For any number and combination of types, the alarm must be able to remember and store members of those types for later use on the callback function.

#### Recommendation

I wouldn't recommend building an alarm capable of storing any combination of cooking supplies.  Keep the type signature of the alarm constant and simple.  If a client want to make the alarm to make breakfast or start a band or launch a rocket-ship, make the client wrap whatever functions and variables they need into a simple functor or lambda function: one that remembers all the variables it needs and only one way to set it off (`operator ()`, called with no arguments).

Comment: Finally got around to actually implementing the topic of this question; coupling templates with your suggestion of using functors works great.

Answer (score 3):

You can use C++11's [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to wrap whatever function you want to call after the timer expires.

Comment: `std::function` is a template, not a type. Specific template instantiations still have a fixed signature.

Comment: Using bind he could(almost completely) forget about the wrapped method's signature. I thought he wanted a way of calling just "some function" to handle the timer expiration event. He could template the `std::function`'s return value and he would have a generic solution. It would be better if OP provides more details anyway.

Comment: @KerrekSB that's easily resolved, make a CallBoundFunction abstract class and have the timer pop run a list of those; the factories just make concrete versions that call their other base's operator(), the actual function.